# Office Interop Word error with Sharepoint 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, office-interop, web-parts, office-automation

I developed a webpart that creates a Word document and exports it to PDF format using `ExportAsFixedFormat`. It worked in my development Sharepoint server. When I deployed it to the production server, I'm getting this error:

> [COMException (0x80004005): Word has encountered a problem.]
>
> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass.ExportAsFixedFormat(String OutputFileName, WdExportFormat ExportFormat, Boolean OpenAfterExport, WdExportOptimizeFor OptimizeFor, WdExportRange Range, Int32 From, Int32 To, WdExportItem Item, Boolean IncludeDocProps, Boolean KeepIRM, WdExportCreateBookmarks CreateBookmarks, Boolean DocStructureTags, Boolean BitmapMissingFonts, Boolean UseISO19005_1, Object& FixedFormatExtClassPtr) +0
> test.PdfExporter.WebParts.PrintPDF.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0() +10785
> Microsoft.SharePoint.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__3() +349
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) +197
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param) +423
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) +95
> test.PdfExporter.WebParts.PrintPDF.PrintPDFUserControl.generateWodDoc(ServiceConfermationList serviceConfermationList) +158
> test.PdfExporter.WebParts.PrintPDF.PrintPDFUserControl.<btnPrint_Click>b__3_0() +2075
> Microsoft.SharePoint.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__3() +349
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) +197
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param) +423
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode) +95
> test.PdfExporter.WebParts.PrintPDF.PrintPDFUserControl.btnPrint_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +94
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +99
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +140
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2749

This is an example of the code used:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

// Create a new Word application
Application wordApp = new Application();

// Create a new document
Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Add();

// Insert content into the document
Paragraph para = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
para.Range.Text = "Hello, World!";

// Export the document as PDF
string pdfFileName = "example.pdf";
doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(pdfFileName, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);

// Clean up
doc.Close();
wordApp.Quit();
```

Notes:

1. I used the `wwwroot` path as the destination for the saved file
2. I use Office 2013.

Can you help me solve the issue that I got?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

If you need to deal with open XML documents only you may consider using the Open XML SDK instead, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information. Otherwise, consider using any third-party components designed for the server-side execution.